# how to add newsletter subscription during registration?

Tags: 7, forms

Here what I want to do. I loaded a checkbox list of taxonomy term on the registration form. Also I have a check box for "subscribe newsletter". so the user can check the his favourit taxonomy and "subscribe newsletter". I want to know how can I alter the submission of register form to gather this data?

Comment: FYI: for newsletter drupal have a good module http://drupal.org/project/simplenews. It provides all these facilities and provides more features for newsletter

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this either by using [Mailchimp Module](http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp)

```
                          OR(by custom coding)
```

You can alter your registration form using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Now in your form you can add add two new elements that is :-

1. A checkbox saying- Signup to receive alerts.
2. A text field to capture email address.

Now you can override your form on submission and pass the email captured above to mailchimp function that adds users to email lists via ajax call.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: tanx . I used the same solution as you offered.